# Angularjs Export HTML table to excel does not support Hebrew characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, excel, export-to-excel

I am using the following code in order to export HTML table to excel file:

```
<div id="table">
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>שלום</td>
                <td>ובטחון</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS

```
var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('table').innerHTM], {
        type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
    });
    saveAs(blob, "Excel.xls");
};
```

The export is working just fine but the Hebrew characters in the output Excel file looks like this:

> ×ž×’×™×¢

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Thanks,
Omri

UPDATE - Found a working solution.
changing the type to text/plain:

```
type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8;"
```

It's not opening the Excel file in the best way but it works.